# Installed Python package spaCy throws following error:

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, spacy

I installed the Python package spaCy in Pycharm successfully. I can see it's installed as well in Pycharm as in the terminal via `python -m spacy validate` (I am using macOS).
Can anyone help me understand following the error, please? I'm really lost. All I am trying to do is import the package, nothing else.
My only code is `import spacy`.
The error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import pipeline
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
  File "pipes.pyx", line 25, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..language import component
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .lang.tokenizer_exceptions import TOKEN_MATCH, URL_MATCH
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy/lang/tokenizer_exceptions.py", line 62, in <module>
    URL_MATCH = re.compile("(?u)" + URL_PATTERN).match
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug for python 2.7 and spacy v2.2.4 or v2.3.0--2.3.2. It should be fixed in v2.3.3+.

Unless you have a particular reason to be using python 2.7, it would be better to switch to python 3.6+.